# Python - Low Level USB Port Control

Tags: python, usb

I want to make a simple python program, which controls my laptop's usb hubs. Nothing extra, just put first usb port's DATA+ channel into HIGH (aka 5V) or LOW (aka 0 V) state.

Comment: ...do you have a question? Learn [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Python is way to highlevel for this problem, this behavior would require you to rewrite the USB Driver of your OS.

Comment: Should I use C? I don't want to go with ASM (I know some other ASMs but sadly I don't know x86 :\)

Comment: As David Grayson already said, better use a microcontroller, you do not want to rewrite the driver (which, by the way, should only be possible on linux)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this.  Even if you knew how to write low-level drivers for your operating system, this is probably not possible because the data pins of USB ports are only designed to output voltages between 0 and 3.3 V.  They are also designed to send and receive USB packets, not arbitrary voltages.

Instead, you should get a small [programmable microcontroller](https://www.pololu.com/category/64/programmable-controllers) with a normal USB interface and use its output pins.